# Issue on Azure Date comparison- GenerateFilterConditionForDate

Tags: c#, azure

The passed value for FromDateTime is {2/8/2018 4:09:45 PM +00:00}
After the below query executed the FromDateTime value gets changed to '2018-02-08T10:39:45.8124746Z'

```
   var query1 = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey),
            TableOperators.And,
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, fromDateTimeOffset.DateTime));
```

The result of above query is

```
(PartitionKey eq 'Valve') and (Timestamp ge datetime'2018-02-08T10:39:45.8124746Z')
```

**My Query**

I could not find where and why this change happen. Any idea, please share.

Comment: probably silly but just to strike out possibility are we sure this is not due to timezone? is it possible to send in UTCTime or something similar that should be more universally same in value?

Comment: The date passed to that method is converted to ToUniversalTime().And so we get FromDateTime as {2/8/2018 4:09:45 PM +00:00} <== this is the time seen on the method parameter(FromDate). Insde the method as soon the above mentioned query executes i.e `var query1` the value is seen as  `....) and (Timestamp ge datetime'2018-02-08T10:39:45.8124746Z')`

Comment: for future readers, v12 of Azure.Data.Tables does not support GenerateFilterConditionForDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GenerateFilterConditionForDate expects DateTimeOffset not DateTime. So when you do DateTimeOffset.DateTime, while its expecting DateTimeOffset, it still seems to create an offset as if the passed DateTime is local. It then seems to readjust that from the passed (UTC time) value.

The actual code of TableQuery class is :

```
public static string GenerateFilterConditionForDate(string propertyName, string operation, DateTimeOffset givenValue)
{
    return GenerateFilterCondition(propertyName, operation, givenValue.UtcDateTime.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), EdmType.DateTime);
}
```

Alternative would be to pass either a new DateTimeOffset object either directly or by creating new DateTimeOffset by passing DateTime in constructor.

You can use below snippet to verify the same.

```
DateTime tp = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
// offset value is in UTC
DateTimeOffset offset = new DateTimeOffset(tp);
DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;

Console.WriteLine(offset);
Console.WriteLine(utc);
CheckOffset(offset.DateTime);

private static void CheckOffset(DateTimeOffset dateTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime.UtcDateTime.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GenerateFilterConditionForDate` is not returning a correctly formatted query `string`, at least not what Azure expects. So, I did it by hand and used the plain `GenerateFilterCondition`, passing the correctly formatted `string`.

```
string lowerLimit = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-2), XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);

// the format is Field + Operator + DateTime as constant + the UTC formated date enclosed single quotes
var filterCondition = @"StartDate ge Datetime'"+lowerLimit+"'";

var query = new TableQuery<JarvisEntity>().Where(filterCondition);

foreach (var entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
{
     //..... your work
}
```